# Play real-time sound buffer using C# Media.SoundPlayer

Tags: c#, buffer, voice, wave, soundplayer

I have developed a system in which a C# program receives sound buffers (byte arrays) from another subsystem. It is supposed to play the incoming buffers continuously. I searched in the web and I decided to use `SoundPlayer`. It works perfectly in the offline mode (play the buffers after receiving them all). However, I have a problem in the real-time mode.

In the real-time mode the program at first waits for a number of buffer arrays (for example 200) to receive and accumulate them. Then it adds a wav header and plays it. However, after that for each next 200 arrays it plays repeatedly the first buffer.

I have read following pages:

[Play wav/mp3 from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340967/play-wav-mp3-from-memory#)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ac2847c-3e2f-458c-b8ff-533728e267e0/c-problems-with-mediasoundplayer?forum=netfxbcl

and according to their suggestions I implemented my code as follow:

```
public class MediaPlayer
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer soundPlayer;

    public MediaPlayer(byte[] buffer)
    {
        byte[] headerPlusBuffer = AddWaveHeader(buffer, false, 1, 16, 8000, buffer.Length / 2); //add wav header to the **first** buffer
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(headerPlusBuffer, true);
        soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(memoryStream);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        soundPlayer.PlaySync();
    }

    public void Play(byte[] buffer)
    {
        soundPlayer.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        soundPlayer.Stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        soundPlayer.PlaySync();
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
if (firstBuffer)
{
    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(dataRaw);
    _mediaPlayer.Play();
}
else
{
    _mediaPlayer.Play(dataRaw);
}
```

Each time `_mediaPlayer.Play(dataRaw)` is called, the first buffer is played again and again; the `dataRaw` is updated though.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: When you have an API that's not designed for streaming playback, there's no good way to add streaming in a wrapper.  Passing it a sequence of blocks will not achieve the correct time between blocks.  You need an API designed for streaming.

Comment: Thank you Ben. So what streaming playback API do you recommend?

Comment: The one I've used is Media Foundation, but that's far too complex for your needs.  Can you use a library?  Try nAudio, you'll need the `BufferedWaveProvider` and `WaveOut` classes.