# C#, playing an audio with 8kHz and unsigned 8-bit in 4 channels

Tags: c#, audio

I need a help with my project. I'm writing a C# program (WinForms)
Program must read a file bytes, and then to play them as an audio.
The task is to play it in 8kHz, 8 bit unsigned, and there are 4 channels of audio flow
Could you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is rather broad. StackOverflow is for specific technical questions. So where are you stuck? Do you have problems reading the file? Do you have problems playing data as audio? Do you insufficiently understand the given parameters? Please ask one specific question.

Comment: Umm... create a WAV file in an audio editor of your choice with the parameters required. Then play the WAV file in your program (see here for some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340967/play-wav-mp3-from-memory

Comment: Ok,thank you guys! I realised, that my question was really broad)
But, now I understand, what I need to do! So, thank you for attention)